# How to access post data from Angular / Ionic to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, json

I'm posting JSON data from Angular / Ionic to PHP, but I'm having trouble accessing the data from PHP.

Here is my php code:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

I saved the $jsonData in the database to see what the data looks like and it looks like this:

```
{"headers":null,"params":{"event_title":"My Event","event_start_date":"2018-01-12","event_end_date":"2018-01-12","post_type":"add"}}
```

When I save the json_decode Associative Array to the database, it just saves it as "Array", so I cannot see what the Array looks like. So I echo the data (as response) to Angular and here is what the $data looks like in my browser's console HttpErrorResponse:

```
"Array↵(↵    [headers] => ↵    
[params] => Array↵  …1-12↵            [post_type] => add↵        )↵↵)↵"
```

There are a few posted data missing from the above response array such as event_title. Maybe the full posted data is there and displayed as "…1-12".

I appreciate any help on this:

1. What am I doing wrong in getting the JSON data to Array in PHP code above?
2. How do I access the data such as "event_title" in my PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get event_title by

```
print_r($data['params']['event_title']);
```